# How to use two differents rec_name in odoo python file

Tags: python, odoo

I have two fields in each class, i need to make relation Many2one between (fn and fn_) and relation Many2one between (ln and ln_). I can't use _rec_name more than one time.

Here is my python file:

```
class ClassOne(models.Model):
    _name = 'moduleT.one'
    _rec_name = 'fn'
    fn = fields.Char("First name", required=True)

    ln = fields.Char("Last name", required=True)

class ClassTwo(models.Model):
    _name = 'moduleT.two'
    fn_ = fields.Many2one('moduleT.one')
    ln_ = fields.Char("Last name")
    ***#TO DO: ln_ = fields.Many2one(ln)***
```

Comment: I really don't understand your requirement. Could you please specifiy it in more detail and maybe with examples?

Comment: i need to make relation fn_= Many2one:(fn), and relation ln_=Many2one(ln)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use related field, instead of what are you doing. `_rec_name` provides display name.

```
class ClassOne(models.Model):
    _name = 'moduleT.one'

    fn = fields.Char("First name", required=True)
    ln = fields.Char("Last name", required=True)

    @api.multi
    def name_get(self):
        result = []
        for record in self:
            result.append((record.id, " ".join(record.fn, record.ln)))
        return result

class ClassTwo(models.Model):
    _name = 'moduleT.two'

    reference = Many2one('moduleT.one')
    fn_ = fields.Char("First name", related='reference.fn')
    ln_ = fields.Char("Last name", related='reference.ln')
```

Many2one field create relation from record of one model to record on another model, as record of `ClassTwo` is already having relation to `moduleT.one` record using field `reference` here, you don't need relate multiple times. For field to field relation, `related` field is used here.

Comment: we can use this reference for an other class?

Comment: yes, reference is nothing but a field name, your can replace any name instead of reference. this is just a related field, many2one type.

Comment: but if we have many record we can know to select one of them, because reference don't let to select by values...

Comment: You can implement `name_get()` method for that, check the updated answer.